# Просмотр изображения в полноэкранном режиме

Tags: android, listview, slider

Подскажите пожалуйста какие библиотеки вы используете для просмотра изображений в FullScreen. Где есть и zoom и перелистование фото (slider).
Хочу при клике на item в ListView открывать картинки во весь экран с возможность перелистывания и увеличения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, самая популярная библиотека, дающая такой функционал (pan, zoom) по ImageView - https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom . Остается реализовать почти обычный `ViewPager`, в котором каждая страница - `ImageViewZoom`. Почти обычный из-за того, что могут пересекаться эвенты нажатия и свайпа, пример совместной работы есть [тут](https://gist.github.com/atermenji/3781644)